# Running a geth light client, how do I resolve the error: "No trusted canonical hash trie"?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

I've been running a geth light client to deploy smart contracts through Truffle Migrations to mainnet. I'm getting: "Error: No trusted canonical hash trie".

Any help in what this entails and how to resolve it?

Comment: which version of geth you're using?

Comment: v 1.8.7 stable.

Comment: I did update to stable 1.8.16 and it still happens

Comment: They also mentioned that not sure about the mainnet; you can create an issue on github to report the problem

Comment: I'm getting the (exact?) same problem with 1.8.7, but with rinkeby.  I'm also getting "Error: no suitable peers available"
It *is* submitting the transactions, btw, but it is not picking up responses properly.

Comment: * correction: error occurs with 1.8.17.

Answer (score 1):

For light clients and maybe more so for super light clients which don't have the state local a get_proof() RPC call will be needed for these use cases.
There is some work being done here: ethereum/EIPs#1186

Answer (score 1):

When starting geth make sure to have `--syncmode "fast"`  rather than  `--syncmode "light"` .

Comment: You may want to explain how this solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since a light client doesn't hold full database, it needs to have a canonical hash to validate a newly received block.

If the node is pruned (or new), it needs to download block bodies and receipts on demand through an ODR interface, then make sure it's covered by a local checkpoint.

Basically it means your node needs to find peers to download data from, with time it should find some and proceed, unless there's a connectivity issue.

Can see the condition that produces this error [here](https://github.com/etclabscore/core-geth/blob/c74f1b8ae5bb3793d1c0b38c4863958e6b217641/light/odr_util.go#L55).

Answer (score 1):

The error message "No trusted canonical hash trie" usually indicates that the Ethereum client you are using (in your case Geth light client) has not fully synchronized with the Ethereum blockchain.

To resolve the issue, you can try the following steps:

- Increase the timeout value in your client configuration file.
- Restart
  your client and allow it to synchronize completely.
- If the issue
  persists, try switching to a different Ethereum client, such as
  Parity or Geth full node.

It's important to note that running a light
client may not always be sufficient for deploying smart contracts to
the Ethereum mainnet, as light clients have limited capabilities
compared to full nodes.